# Android including XML and their Java class

Tags: java, android

I am making an app where I have a few menus (about 7 of them) and a starting screen that is it's own menu.

To make things easier to read, I've decided I want to separate each menu and the starting screen from the main activity and include them when the app runs.  But I'd like to include a java class per XML file.

What I have so far is a starting page called `activity_start_page.xml` it has it's own java class called `StartPage.java`.  This all works fine and dandy.

Inside of this start page, I have included an xml layout called `part_start_scroll.xml` and I'd like to have it's java included as well, `part_start_scroll.java`.

On top of both of these, I'd like to do the same thing with each setting sub section.  I'll have all of the subsections like so:

```
part_settings_camera.xml
part_settings_email.xml
part_settings_security.xml
etc...
```

I'd like to include each one of these as well as a java class that will accompany them.

My XML file for `activity_start_page` includes all of the layouts:

```
    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <include layout="@layout/part_settings_session" android:id="@+id/part_settings_session"/>
        <include layout="@layout/part_settings_camera" android:id="@+id/part_settings_camera"/>
        <include layout="@layout/part_settings_security" android:id="@+id/part_settings_security"/>
        <include layout="@layout/part_settings_social" android:id="@+id/part_settings_social"/>
        <include layout="@layout/part_settings_printer" android:id="@+id/part_settings_printer"/>
        <include layout="@layout/part_settings_email" android:id="@+id/part_settings_email"/>
        <include layout="@layout/part_settings_about" android:id="@+id/part_settings_about"/>
    </ViewFlipper>
```

and the `StartPage.java` handles the flipper to show the specific view depending on what menu item was clicked:

```
//One of these for each menu button
menu_about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(6);
        ...
    }
});
```

All of this works, except for the Java that accompanies each layout.

In my `StartPage.java`, I tried to use `startActivity()` to include the java, but it only works on one java class and not multiples.  I got this from another question I asked earlier:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(StartPage.this, part_start_scroll.class)); 
        startActivity(new Intent(StartPage.this, part_settings_session.class));
        finish();
    }
}, 1000);
```

The above does not work, but if I were to do just a single class, it works just fine.

So my ultimate question is: **How do I include all of these other java files so I can compartmentalize my code?**  Second to that, but should have no bearing on the answer is: Is this inefficient?

Comment: Can you explain what does those "Java classes" intended to do?

Comment: @aelimill Those classes are for setting and retrieving the specific options in the menu from shared preferences and also handle specialized buttons and integration elements